# how to remove first element of duplicate in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

pardon my English , i want to remove first element of an array of object if it occur twice

here is the array=[{id:34,value:45}, {id:23,value:35}, {id:34,value:28}]

i want to remove first element because third element's id is same as first element

output should be array=[{id:23,value:35}, {id:34,value:28}]

Comment: what would happen, if it occurs multiple time?

Comment: @SumanMajhi only keep the last one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: This should be sufficient: `Object.values(array.reduce((acc, itm) => ({...acc, [itm.id]: {...itm}}), {}));`. It iterates using `.reduce`, removes duplicates by keeping last element based on `id`, creates an intermediate object (resulting from `.reduce`) and gets the `Object.values` to get an array back. All of it - in one line. :-) PS: It uses shallow copy (by `...` spread-operator) so changes to the original array will not impact the result generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you an array with the *last* value for duplicated elements, in preserved order. If you want exactly the 2nd one you need an extra flag

```js
array=[{id:34,value:45}, {id:23,value:35}, {id:34,value:28}]




const obj = array.reduce ( (acc,cur,index) => {
  acc[cur.id] = {index:cur};
  return acc;
},{});

const output = Object.values(obj).sort( (a,b) => a.index - b.index).map( ({index:val}) => val )

console.log(output)
```

Comment: i want the last one, not the  second one

Comment: Why not this @malarres: `Object.values(array.reduce((acc, itm) => ({...acc, [itm.id]: {...itm}}), {}));`. This should give the array with keeping last element in case of duplicate `id`s.

Answer (score 1):

[Get all unique values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

```js
let arr = [{id:34,value:45}, {id:23,value:35}, {id:34,value:28}]
var unique = arr.reverse().filter((v, i, a) => a.map(e => e.id).indexOf(v.id) === i);
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: i want to remove the first and keep the last

Comment: @gipixo my answer keep the last

Answer (score 1):

A solution using **ES6**

```js
const array = [
  { id: 34, value: 45 },
  { id: 23, value: 35 },
  { id: 34, value: 28 },
];

const convertToArray = array.map(({ id, value }) => [id, value]);
const convertToSet = Object.fromEntries(convertToArray);
const revertAsCleanedArray = Object.entries(convertToSet);
const cleanedArrayOfObjects = revertAsCleanedArray.map(([id, value]) => ({id, value}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```js
let array = [{id:34,value:45}, {id:23,value:35}, {id:34,value:28}]

let result = array.filter((x,i) => array.findLastIndex(y => y.id == x.id) == i)

console.log(result)
```